# Unable to access H2 Database

Tags: corda

I have implemented the Hellow world example, https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-running.html, on two machines. Where I am running Notary and Party A on one machine and Party B on another machine.

After posting the transaction, I am able to check transaction through Shell by running vault query but I am not getting any H2 DB URL to connect and check the transaction in H2 DB. Please help me know , where I can find the H2 DB URL? I think user name should sa and password null.  I have installed the latest H2 DB on my systems.

Please help

[I tried with DBVisulaiser but no Corda tables are reflecting in schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPUJK.png)

Comment: please find this link https://docs.corda.net/head/node-database-access-h2.html#connecting-directly-to-the-node-s-persistence-mv-db-file

Comment: The DB url is present in the node's terminal windows

Answer (score 0):

You can override the H2 database URL by specifying the URL as below in build.gradle in deployNodes task.

```
node {
        name "O=Notary,L=Delhi,C=IN"
        notary = [validating : false]
        p2pPort 10004
        ......
        extraConfig = ['h2Settings.address' : 'localhost:1000']
    }
```